# Can JS be isolated within the shadow DOM as it is in an iframe in SO's code snippets?

Tags: javascript, web-component, shadow-dom, custom-element

The SO site appears to use an iframe to run code snippets. Can any form of web components accept user-provided JavaScript and run it in isolation within the shadow DOM only?

I tried both a simple shadow DOM and a custom element example by appending a script tag, and that script can alter the DOM outside the shadow DOM in both instances. Is there a way to isolate the JS?

This [almost ten-year-old answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27292375/why-can-i-call-function-which-is-in-a-shadow-dom?rq=3) says, No; but wondered if anything has changed. This [eight-year-old answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28517417/shadow-dom-is-it-possible-to-encapsulate-js/?answertab=scoredesc#tab-top) seems to imply that web components can isolate the JS but it's not very clear, at least not to me.

Perhaps, if it were possible, SO and W3schools would be using them
instead of iframes.

The introduction of this [MDN document](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Components) gives the impression that the JS would be isolated unless "functionality" means something other than JS.

> Web Components is a suite of different technologies allowing you to create reusable custom elements — with their functionality encapsulated away from the rest of your code — and utilize them in your web apps.

Thank you.

Comment: No, ``<script>`` always runs in ``window`` scope

Answer (score 0):

No, the shadow DOM is an unrelated type of isolation. Even if there were no way for a particular script to interfere with other scripts on the page or access any DOM outside a designated shadow DOM, the script would still be running on the same origin and so be completely unsafe for untrusted code – able to make arbitrary same-origin requests with credentials, for example.

> This [eight-year-old answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28517417/shadow-dom-is-it-possible-to-encapsulate-js/39366126#39366126) seems to imply that web components can isolate the JS

I don’t think any part of that answer implies isolating JS, only that inline scripts in a template will run when inserted into the document.

Comment: It was the first sentence that gave that impression: "Web-components, being used through HTML imports, encapsulate both Shadow DOM HTML and related script." Guess it depends on what is intended by "encapsulate." But makes no difference, really, because if it can't be done then it can't be done regardless of what that answer's author intended. But, I just noticed that I linked to the wrong answer. I meant the top one. I'll fix that.